# How to create/update Global Value Set in apex?

Tags: apex, set, global

Is there a way to Insert/Upsert a Global value set in apex?

Answer (score 3):

The ability to directly manipulate metadata in Apex is accomplished with the Apex Metadata API.

Direct manipulation of metadata is also highly risky.

For this reason, the Apex Metadata is limited to working with the following metadata as of the writing of this answer (as documented in the Apex developer [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_supported_types.htm)):

- Page Layouts
- Custom MD Type Records

You can read more about the Apex MDAPI in this Trailhead [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api/apex_metadata_api_security#Tdxn4tBK-heading3) as well.

There are workarounds to manipulate other metadata that involve invoking the API via callback from the same org, of which there are a number of examples out there to check out. For instance, the `apex-toolingapi` [library](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) can help you do that.

Comment: Thank you pchittum your answer is appreciated, I will check'em out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Tooling API** to update the **Global Value Set** via **APEX**.

```
public class ToolingUtility {
    
    public static void updateGlobalPicklist (String apiName){  
        
        String queryURL = '/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query?q=Select+id,MasterLabel,Description,fullname,metadata+from+GlobalValueSet+Where+developername=\''+apiName+'\'';
        String retrieveResponse = sendRequest(null,queryURL,'GET');
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(retrieveResponse);
        String retrieveURL ='';
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.START_OBJECT){
                parser.nextToken();
            }
            if(parser.getCurrentName() == 'URL'){
                retrieveURL = parser.getText();
            }
        }
        
        if(retrieveURL != ''){
            //Replace the below 1 line to dynamically generate your metadata JSON using a Wrapper Class container and converting it in JSON
            String fieldinfo = '{"Metadata" : {"customValue" : [ {"color" : null,"default" : false,"description" : null,"isActive" : null, "label" : "RTYT", "urls" : null,"valueName" : "RTYT"}],"description" : null,"masterLabel" : "Vehicle","sorted" : false,"urls" : null}}';
            String extractResponse = sendRequest(fieldinfo,retrieveURL,'PATCH');
        }
        
    
    }
    
    public static String sendRequest(String fieldInfo, string metadataURL, string reqType){    
    /*______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________   
    M1-Σ : This method sends the HTTP request to perform the action 
    ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________  
    I1.  Name: sendRequest
    Type: String
    Description: Response Body
    ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________   
    O1-Σ : Type: String - Information of Metadata or the specific field  
    O2-Σ : Type: String - URl for the metadata to be extracted or inserted
    O3-Σ : Type: String - HTTP request type
    ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        if(fieldInfo!= NULL){
          req.setBody(fieldInfo);  
        }
        if(reqType == 'PATCH'){
            req.setMethod('POST');
            metadataURL += '?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
        } else {
            req.setMethod(reqType);
        }
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+metadataURL);
        Http httpreq = new Http();
        HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nishant, I will see if it works.